# If $\langle\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y), x-y\rangle \geq 0$ then $H_f \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that for $f:U \subset \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, if $\langle\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y), x-y\rangle \geq 0$ $\forall x,y \in U$ then $H_f \geq 0$ where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the scalar product, and $H_f$ denotes the Hessian matrix of $f$. Can anybody help me with this proof?

Comment: That might lead us to convexity

Comment: If the given condition is true, then $f$ is convex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that $f$ is $C^2$. Then $H_f$ can be viewed as the derivative of the function $\nabla f : U \to \mathbb{R}$, i.e.,
$$
 \nabla f(x+h) = \nabla f(x) + H_f(x)h + R(x,h), \quad \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|R(x,h)\|}{\|h\|} = 0.
$$
Then
$$
 \langle H_f(x) h,h\rangle = \langle \nabla f(x+h)-\nabla f(x),h\rangle - \langle R(x,h),h \rangle \geq  -\langle R(x,h),h\rangle,
$$
so that if $v$ is a fixed unit vector and $0 \neq s \in \mathbb{R}$, setting $h = sv$, we get
$$
 s^2 \langle H_f(x)v,v\rangle \geq - s\langle R(x,sv),v\rangle.
$$
What happens if you divide this inequality by $s^2$, and take limits as $s \to 0$?